# Is it possible to refer to an additional .txt-file inside the CMakeLists.txt?

Tags: cmake, cmake-language

I have a CMakeLists.txt for my project. There are a few lines I want to exclude into a new seperate .txt-file.
Is there a command in cmake-language that refers to a .txt-file as input? (like  `\input` in Latex)

Thank you!

Comment: @Botje thank you for the suggestion! Honestly I struggle with fully understanding the thread since I have barely any experience with cmake. So if I replace some lines in my CMakeLists.txt with `find_package(Module)` and add the file "FindModule.cmake" containing those lines, could that be a solution?

Comment: ...no. You should just `include("${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/foo.txt")`